# Google Maps - How to add a number to a latitude/longitude to change the coordinate

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

It's supposed to be simple. I have experience in Java, but apparently it's not the same in JavaScript.

```
var marker = markers[0];
var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();
var newcoords = newCoords(lat + 50, lng + 50);
marker.animateTo(newcoords);
console.log(lat + ", " + lat+50);
```

markers is an array that, in addMarker(), gets appended to by:

```
markers.push(marker);
```

newCoords() is a function that I made; it just returns a `google.maps.LatLng` with the coordinates given.

animateTo() is a method that's part of an external library to animate markers. It's called markeranimate.js. It works, I tested it. Nothing wrong with that.

When I log the output there, it gives the right coordinate, but the `lat+50` gives the right coordinate, but **with 50 appended to it.**

```
42.3656132, 42.365613250 <-- see?
```

It's the same thing with the longitude.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your "numbers" are strings, so the `+` operator is performing string concatenation.

Comment: @Pointy How do I fix this then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Pointy for pointing out that the `+` in front of the 50 is being concatenated because it is being done in a `console.log`. Grouping the lat and the 50 gives me the correct result, and I don't even need the parseFloat anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you use parseFloat on your coordinates and then add your number it will work.

Like this: 
x = "3"

var newNumber = parseFloat(x) + 4

Comment: In your case it would be `parseFloat(lat)+50`

Comment: No, it removes the decimals.

Comment: Oops, try parseFloat?

Comment: No. Same result as without parseFloat.

Comment: It works like this: `var x = "2.34"
parseFloat(x)+23
25.34`

Comment: Is it still concatenating?

Comment: Yes. I did `parseFloat(lat)+50` but had the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96436/discussion-between-quade-dumont-and-thejuniorprogrammer).

Comment: @TheJuniorProgrammer there is no possible way that `parseFloat(lat) + 50` would contatenate "50" onto the end of the value.

Comment: @Pointy Well, guess what? My log shows 42.365613250

Comment: @TheJuniorProgrammer the point is that that means you *think* you've correctly changed the code, but you really haven't.

Comment: @Pointy This is my code, at this moment: `console.log(lat + ", " + parseFloat(lat)+50);`

Comment: @TheJuniorProgrammer note that your `console.log()` code has to account for the fact that it's being done in the context of the string concatenation going on for the comma etc. You have to parenthesize the `parseFloat(lat) + 50` subexpression or else it'll still be treated as part of the string concatenation.

Comment: @Pointy Applause for you sir! Thanks :D

Comment: I apologize for sounding snarky; I thought you were talking about the `newCoords()` function argument, where no extra parens would be necessary.